# If my pagefile is disabled on Windows, should I still be seeing Hard Faults?

Tags: windows-7, memory, pagefile

I am running Windows 7 with 32GB of RAM and have disabled my PageFile.

However, in Resource Monitor, the Memory tab is still showing values for `Hard Faults/sec`. I've read that this metric should display how many times per second a program is being read out of the PageFile on disk.

Given that I have mine disabled (and have rebooted), why am I still seeing non-zero values for this metric? Also, might this graph include Soft Faults too?

[image: Screenshot of zero page file and still seeing hard faults / sec]

Comment: Why do you have pagefile disabled?

Comment: I have 32GB of physical RAM installed and my hard drive is as slow as molasses after a cold winter's day in Wisconsin. I'd rather take my system down if I push past 32GB than make it become unresponsive. In other words, personal preference :P

Comment: It could count new allocations as a hard fault but I don't know for sure. Can you run `perfmon` and create a trace that contains all of the possible memory traces and post that?

Comment: pagefault has nothing to do with pagefile. It means the system needs data that it must read from disk because the data are not already in the RAM.

Comment: The label on the graph is not `PageFault` but `HardFault`. Also, a `PageFault` would not count fresh reads from disk because that data was not already in virtual memory. In a `PageFile` free system, the only way you should be able to generate a `PageFault` (as I understand virtual memory) is by reading data from existing memory cache. There should also be 0 `Hard Faults`.

Comment: I will post the `perfmon` trace.

Comment: Jason: You don't understand virtual memory.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan You're right. I really didn't understand this at the time. I've left this for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've read that this metric should display how many times per second a program is being read out of the PageFile on disk.

Then you've clearly read some bogus rubbish.  It's quite wrong to think that in a demand-paged operating system the only possible backing store for memory pages is the system page file.  Program image files containing the code and (read-only/untainted) data for running programs are another possibility.  Then there are explicitly memory mapped files.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2007).  [*Do not throw those paging files away just yet.*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-throw-those-paging-files-away.html).  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: This is correct. And that article you linked is a very good primer on the subject. I usually refer people to it too.

Comment: So `Hard Faults` apply to more than disk reads? I was under the understanding that Microsoft made a specific disambiguation between `Page Faults` and `Hard Faults` where the `Hard` in `Hard Faults` is the same hard in hard drive. Also, of course I don't think the only backing store is the page file. I think it is virtual memory and I was under the understanding that the `Hard Faults` metric ignored "non-slow" PageFault (virtual memory) locations.

Comment: I do wonder where on Earth you are reading all of this bogus rubbish.  You need to find, or if one doesn't exist add, a "What is meant by 'Hard Faults' in Windows' Resource Monitor?" question.  Because almost none of what you just wrote was right.