# Tell Windows 8 not to write to pagefile at certain times?

Tags: windows-8, memory, pagefile

I play a 3-D game on my laptop that uses about 1.2 GB of RAM, typically. The laptop has 6 GB of RAM, and Task Manager shows approximately 2.5 GB of RAM in use when my game is running.

I have read [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/457301/why-does-windows-7-use-the-page-file-when-theres-free-physical-ram) about why Win 7 uses the page file when there is "free" RAM, and that Windows actually mucks around with the "free" RAM to try and make my future experience better.

However, the problem I have is that sometimes it decides to write some other app out to the pagefile, which causes my game to run very slowly for 30 - 60 seconds. (Apparently my laptop's HDD doesn't write very fast). I know this is what it's doing because I tab to Resource Monitor which I already had open, and see heavy writes to C:\pagefile.sys, but it is still showing only the 2.5 GB of RAM in use.

When I am playing my game I don't want it to try and second guess what I'm about to do, I just want my game to run optimally and preferably nothing else should write to the HDD at all. (My game does do a reasonable amount of HDD reading during normal gameplay, but little to no writing).

Is it possible to instruct Windows 8 to not try to be clever and page out other apps while my game is running?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "pause" the pagefile, maybe turn it off completely...

But you could **close as many programs as possible** before running your game, that way the pagefile *should* be quieter while your playing... unless it's your game that's running out of real ram & getting swapped to the pagefile.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than turning it off, I would choose static size and made sure that pagefile.sys isn't fragmented. [Defraggler](https://www.piriform.com/defraggler) can defrag chosen files.

Read those 2 topics:

- [If my pagefile is disabled on Windows, should I still be seeing Hard Faults?](https://superuser.com/questions/705545/if-my-pagefile-is-disabled-on-windows-should-i-still-be-seeing-hard-faults?rq=1)
- [Should I disable swap file if I have lots of RAM or should I move it to a virtual RAM drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/810170/should-i-disable-swap-file-if-i-have-lots-of-ram-or-should-i-move-it-to-a-virtua?rq=1)